# How to use 2 MySQL SELECT Statements in one PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please help me figure out how to put the following two statements into one query. Your help is much appreciated.

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT COUNT(id) as total_cat_votes FROM votes WHERE category_id="1"';
$sql2 = 'SELECT COUNT(nominee_id') as total_nom_votes FROM votes WHERE category_id="1" AND nominee_id="16"';
```

My Idea here is I have a table called `votes` and I want to get the number of total votes for a specific category under `category_id` as well as the different total votes of each nominee under `nominee_id`. I hope I am clear enough.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM()` for the second count with a condition, using `sum` with a condition will result in a `boolean` as 0 or 1,also using aggregate functions without grouping them will result in a single row

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total_cat_votes,
SUM(nominee_id='16') as total_nom_votes
FROM votes 
WHERE category_id='1'
```